# Is this solution to show that the Ideal given by the kernel of$ f \in R \mapsto f(0,0) \in \mathbb C[X,Y]$ is not finitely generated correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, modules, ideals

Let $R \subseteq \mathbb C[X,Y]$ be the subring of all polynomials $f \in \mathbb C[X,Y]$ that can be written as $f = g(X)+X ·h(X,Y)$

**a. Let $I \subset R$ be the kernel of the evaluation map $R \rightarrow C$ given by$ f \mapsto f(0,0)$. Show that the ideal $ I$ is not finitely generated.**

**b. Conclude that in general a submodule of a finitely generated module need not be finitely generated**

I previously asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4771300).

I got an aswer there, but it looks pretty convoluted to me, there are several things I am not convinced about, and with an answer already there  no one else is helping. this question is just to get my solution checked and possibly another suggestion

**I have a proposal, but I need someone to tell me if it is correct/ help me fill in the details**
I've been browsing around and looks like the standard procedure is to get a contradiction in the equation that expresses an element of the set that I want to prove not being finitely generated as generated by the elements of a finite generator set.
I am basically drawing inspiration from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2423002).

**My proposal:**

Let $ev(f):=f(0,0)$ denote the evaluation map.

The first step is to realized that the polynomials in $R$ can be written as $ f= g(0)+X\tilde h(X,Y)$, while those in the ideal as $ f=X\tilde h(X,Y)$.

$I= \text{Ker (ev)}=\{f \in R: ev(f)=f(0,0)=0\}=\{ f(x,y)=g(x)+x·h(x,y): g(0)=0\}=X\mathbb C[X;Y]$

I supposed the question is asking about the ideal being generated as $R$-module? I am not sure if this question is compatible with regarding a ring with unity as we do in my course, because that ideal does not contain the unity.

The ideal can be seen as generated by monomials of the form $f_k=xy^k$, so $I=\langle x, xy, xy^2, \dots \rangle$.

By absurd suppose that $I$ is finitely generated. then $\exists$ polynomials $f_1, f_2,...,f_n \in I$ such that $\forall f \in I, f=\sum_{i=1}^{n} r_if_i$  with $r_i \in R$.

Take the highest $y$ power appearing in each generator in $\{f_1, \dots, f_m\}$ and call this number $N$, then $xy^{N+1}\not\in I$.

**If this is wrong, why? Can you suggest how to fix it?**

Comment: This is the right approach.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the kernel should look differently. E.g. Y is in the kernel but not divisible by X. Thus, not contained in your proposal of the kernel.

Comment: @nilsw I forgot to describe what $R$ was (although it was in the linked question), I added it to the beginning of the post, now you see $Y$ is not in $R$, since it can't be written in the form $g(X)+X ·h(X,Y)$